# Regular expression to parse JSON

Tags: php, regex, json

I need help with writing regular expression for this pattern in PHP:

```
[[{"type":"media","view_mode":"small","fid":"1","attributes":{"width":0,"height":0,"src":"http://localhost/x.png"}}]]
```

This is part of the text and I am trying to replace this by something else.

Would like to use `preg_replace_all()` but can't figure out what would be the pattern. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you say you need to identify these JSON-strings inside a normal string, you could use this pattern:

```
'/\[\[.*?]]/s'
```

meaning:

```
\[\[    # match two consecutive '['-s
.*?     # reluctantly match any character
]]      # match two consecutive ']'-s
```

Because of the `s` flag, the `.` in the regex will also match line breaks.

Demo:

```
$text = '<p>blahhah blahaa blahhah blahaablahhah blahaablahhah 
    blahaablahhah blahaablahhah blahaablahhah blahaablahhah 
    blahaablahhah blahaa [[{"type":"media","view_mode":"small",
    "fid":"1","attributes":{"width":0,"height":0,"src":
    "localhost/d7mw/sites/…;}}]] more blah more blah more blah 
    more blahmore blah more blahmore blah more blahmore blah 
    more blahmore blah more blahmore blah more blahmore blah 
    more blahmore blah more blahmore blah more blahmore blah 
    more blah</p>';
preg_match_all('/\[\[.*?]]/s', $text, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

which will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => [[{"type":"media","view_mode":"small",
    "fid":"1","attributes":{"width":0,"height":0,"src":
    "localhost/d7mw/sites/…;}}]]
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like someone understood the question. Will try this :)

Comment: Note that I only understood it after you posted the fact that this JSON string was inside some other string.

Comment: I did write "This is part of some text" in the original question. Thanks, Also while you are at it whats the best way to strip out front and end "[[" so that I can use json_decode to convert it into a php object/array.

Comment: You could use some look arounds: `preg_match_all('/(?<=\[\[).*?(?=]])/s', $text, $matches)`, or group (and then use) only the inner part: `preg_match_all('/\[\[(.*?)]]/s', $text, $matches)`

Comment: Hi, Can you tell me what would be the regex for the same in Javascript? I tried some variations but String.match() doesnt return stuff.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like JSON encoded data, which you can parse cleanly with [**json_decode**](http://de.php.net/json_decode), and put together again with [**json_encode**](http://de.php.net/json_encode). No need for regexes here.

Comment: Nope, though its json I need to identify this pattern passed from the form and then replace it. I need to first identify this from other text.

Comment: Okay, so what exactly is the pattern?

Comment: <p>blahhah blahaa  blahhah blahaablahhah blahaablahhah blahaablahhah blahaablahhah blahaablahhah blahaablahhah blahaablahhah blahaa [[{"type":"media","view_mode":"small","fid":"1","attributes":{"width":0,"height":0,"src":"http://localhost/d7mw/sites/default/files/styles/thumbnail/logo.png"}}]] more blah more blah more blah more blahmore blah more blahmore blah more blahmore blah more blahmore blah more blahmore blah more blahmore blah more blahmore blah more blahmore blah more blahmore blah more blah</p> Lets say this is text.