# Javascript Regular Expression to parse JSON

Tags: javascript, regex

I asked a question about regular expression in PHP (which got answered), I need help with same regular expression in javascript, here is the link to previous question. [Regular expression to parse JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015320/need-help-with-writing-regular-expression)

Again I am not looking to get JSON.parse and get the json object, I need to find the regex for the pattern.

Thanks

Comment: have you even bothered to try, the pattern will be the same, and the syntax is trivial to google

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
var matches = text.match(/\[\[.*?\]\]/);
```

`matches[0]` will be the matched string.

Since the `DOTALL` PCRE option isn't supported in Javascript, you'd have to use a regular expression like that:

```
var matches = text.match(/\[\[(?:\s|.)*?\]\]/);
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped, my mistake was that I was using quotes around pattern.

Comment: You can actually use quotes in JS too, using the object construct `RegExp`, like f.e. `myRegExp = new RegExp("[a-z]+",options)` and then using the generated regular expression with `match`: `matches = text.match(myRegExp)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
/\[\[.*?\]\]/g
```

G - Global (find more than once)

Comment: `/m enables "multi-line mode". In this mode, the caret and dollar match before and after newlines in the subject string.`. Thus, isn't the `m` option senseless?

Answer (score 0):

for complex objects, you can further try this -

```
\{.*\:\{.*\:.*\}\}

{"ABC":{"Prop1":false,"Prop2":"abc","Prop3":false}}
```

Tested it @ http://www.regextester.com/